# Karate parallel runner failed in Eclipse

Tags: rest, karate

I renamed few feature files, updated those names in karate-config.js and since then I am not able to run the feature file. I am getting this issue second time

```
17:04:51.093 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - Karate version: 0.8.0
17:04:51.212 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - karate parallel runner failed: 
Karate version: 0.8.0
====================================================
elapsed time: 0.11 | total thread time: 0.00
features:     1 | threads:   1 | efficiency: 0.00
scenarios:    0 | failed:    0 | skipped:    0
====================================================
*** runner exception stack trace ***
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.parallel(CucumberRunner.java:121)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.parallel(CucumberRunner.java:63)
    at karatetest.runnertest.testParallel(runnertest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.replaceTokens(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:117)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.createExampleScenario(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:57)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberExamples.createExampleScenarios(CucumberExamples.java:28)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.ScenarioOutlineWrapper.<init>(ScenarioOutlineWrapper.java:48)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureWrapper.<init>(FeatureWrapper.java:195)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.FeatureWrapper.fromFile(FeatureWrapper.java:75)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateRuntimeOptions.getRuntime(KarateRuntimeOptions.java:83)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateFeature.getRuntime(KarateFeature.java:69)
    at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.lambda$parallel$0(CucumberRunner.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Tried updating karate version, cleaning and building project still no luck,
Can someone help?

Comment: Yes, I am not very regular, I have accepted the answer. Could you please help me with the above issue? @PeterThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if 0.9.0.RC5 works for you ? It will be released-final within a week.

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/v0.9.0

If you still have a problem, you have to follow this process, else we can't help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue